# FastAPI default response for specific status

Tags: python, fastapi

here we can declare what status code should be sent to client when the endpoint is called:

```
@router.post("/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

the problem I faced for a response body I must return some something be it a `JSONResponse` or `PlainTextResponse` and I wonder if it's possible to not return anything in the router body, but define a default behavior and response for any status code like this for example:

```
@router.post("/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_post(req: post_schemas.Post):
    # create the post record
    # I wanna get rid of this part and do this automatically in a way
    return PlainTextResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, content="Created")
```

and the client gets "Created" message instead of null

**EDIT**
This is what I came up with

```
responses = {200: "OK", 201: "Created"}

@app.middleware("http")
async def no_response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    if (
        response.status_code in responses
        and int(response.headers["content-length"]) == 4
    ):
        return PlainTextResponse(
            status_code=response.status_code, content=responses.get(response.status_code)
        )
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable with [middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/)

It can get access to the response before it's returned to the client. Meaning you can write custom logic there and replace it if needed

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def no_response_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    if is_null_response(response) and response.status_code == 201: # Maybe just a check for 201
        return MyDefaultResponse
    return response
```

Comment: actually I came up with using a middleware last night and it works, but for checking if the response is null, I had no clue of doing it in a more clean way. where may I be able to find `is_null_response`? I checked but I couldn't find it

Comment: @HosseinGholami actually it's a name I came up with, you can't import it anywhere. So it's something one should write themselves. My guess would be checking the body, the headers and maybe just bytes.  Have to make sure that you don't catch 201 responses with proper return body.

Comment: okey,I'm checking the length of the response. I'm gonna add what I have coded in my question